# PHP Warning: ftp_login(): Login with USER first

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to connect and log in to my FTP server. I connect fine but when i login, ftp_login() returns false and a warning like this:

`PHP Warning: ftp_login(): Login with USER first.`

My code is below.

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");

echo "Connected to $ftp_server\n";

$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

var_dump($login);
var_dump(error_get_last());

echo "Logged in to $ftp_server\n";
```

Tried to search for answers but not much information on the net.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `$ftp_username` a valid user string?

Comment: Hello, Markus.

Yup, i have already logged in from my local machine to the same server. The problem is when I run this on a the client's machine, it displays the error above.

Comment: I think it is something with SSL certificate. Can you try using `ftp_connect` instead of `ftp_ssl_connect` to make sure it depends on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a firewall issue. Make sure your FTP Server's firewall allows inbound connection on the port you are trying to connect to. In my case, port 990.

Thanks.